# Windows 7 BSOD when connecting/disconneting to/from VPN network

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I have a VPN connection set up in network connections (so it's direct, not through Cisco VPN or similar). Sometimes when I click on it, I get the BSOD and my computer restarts. The message is "IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL" and I can't seem to find the pattern. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if someone get's this problem, the solution to mine was ShrewSoft VPN Client. Once I updated to the latest version the problem vanished.